# Serialized string to object

Tags: javascript, json, serialization

I have a serialized string like `a=4&b=2&c=7`. I need this as an object like this: `{ a:4, b:2, c:7 }`. serializeArray() just outputs a useless array like this:

`[0: { name: "a", value:4 }`
`1: { name: "b", value:2 }]`

How can I serialize a form as an object?

Thanks!

Comment: JSON.parse and JSON.serialize are your friends

Comment: @RegisPortalez JSON.serialize does not even exist, and JSON.parse parses a JSON string to an object.

Comment: ok stringify. sorry for the typo. why do you serialize this way? What is the serializeArray function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would split the string then parse each element of the array like so :

```
var string = 'a=4&b=2&c=7';

var split = string.split('&') 

var newObj = {};
split.forEach(function(d, i) { 
  newObj[i] = {
    name: d.substring(0, d.indexOf('=')),
    value: d.substring(d.indexOf('=') + 1)
  }
})

console.log(newObj)
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/59x3bfkL/1/